# Can I use inherited values in Less?

Tags: css, less

I have a class `.card` which includes a **lot** of absolute positioned elements.

```
.card {
    height: 400px;
    width: 200px;

    .name {
        position:absolute;
        left: 34px;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create easily many different sizes for `.card`

Like

```
.card.xs {
    .createSizedCard(0.5);
}

.createSizedCard(@factor){
    height: 400px * factor;
    width: 200px * @factor;
    // etc
}
```

---

So. This was obviously just an example, my actual CSS includes way more classes. The question is: can I use something like `@inherited` in my `.createSizedCard` mixin instead of have to declare my values a second time?

I know I could use variables, but I would like to avoid that.

Or alternatively: can I use a concrete value from another class? Like

```
height: .card[height] * @factor;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot inherit the property values from another class and use it. But you can set the default properties (and their calculation logic) of the `.card` class to a ruleset or mixin like in below snippets and call it. The same can be done using a wrapper mixin also.

Here is the ruleset version where the `height`, `width` and `factor` are set within the caller's scope before calling the ruleset.

```
@card: {
  height: @height * @factor;
  width: @width * @factor;
};

.card{
  @factor: 1;
  @height: 400px;
  @width: 200px;
  @card();
  &.xs{
    @factor: 0.5;
    @card();
  }
  &.lg{
    @factor: 2;
    @card();
  }
}
```

Below is a mixin version of how it can be done. It is very similar to the ruleset version except that it can take an input parameter directly.

```
.card(@factor) {
  height: @height * @factor;
  width: @width * @factor;
};
.card{
  @height: 400px;
  @width: 200px;
  .card(1);
  &.xs{
    .card(0.5);
  }
  &.lg{
    .card(2);
  }
}
```

The above when compiled would result in the below CSS:

```
.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
}
.card.xs {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
.card.lg {
  height: 800px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

---

Alternately, if the factor is constant and all card elements would need rules for all sizes then you could create a mixin like the below:

```
.generate-card(@height; @width) {
  height: @height;
  width: @width;
  &.xs{
    height: @height * 0.5;
    width: @width * 0.5;
  }
  &.lg{
    height: @height * 2;
    width: @width * 2;
  }
}

.card {
  .generate-card(400px; 200px);
}
.card-2 {
  .generate-card(450px; 150px);
}
```